# How to make universal image loader load image buttons?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'am sorry for the dumb question but I'am still a beginner.
I'am using universal image loader :  https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader
(Android, Eclipse)

and I don't know how to make it load my image buttons(nearly 30 imagebuttons per layout), I don't want to change anything in the image I just want it to display it as it is in the xml file.

So if you could tell me what code should I type that would be great, Thanks

for example if I have this ImageButton set up in my java file:

```
ImageButton staff = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.staff);
```

and my java file is called MainActivity and this image is saved in my drawable folder what should I do.

a part of my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

SoundPool sp;
int soundId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sp = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundId = sp.load(kh2hd.this, R.raw.btnclick, 1);

    Picasso.with(this).load(R.drawable.staff).into(staff);
    ImageButton staff = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.staffbtn);

    staff.setOnClickListener(this);

}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.staffbtn:
        sp.play(soundId, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
        startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.INFO"));
        break;
```

Comment: Just for double check, do you requiring to load these images from network?

Comment: No all of them are from the app itself, I'am not downloading anything from network. @Paritosh

Comment: Shall I give you single line code with Picasso library? It works great even for network download...

Comment: do you want to load image either from url or local ?

Comment: about picasso when it wants the url of the image what should I type if it's an image which is not on a network? and yeah sure!

Comment: @MayurChudasama , local

Comment: hello friend.. your problem is upload image in imageButton right? using universal image loader

Comment: ImageButton staff = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.staffbtn); this line should be before Picasso.with()...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download Picasso library from [here](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Add it to your build path. Import this library to your code file.

For loading from web url:

```
String url = "http://example.com"

Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(url).into(imageView);
```

For loading from drawable:

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.imageFile).into(imageView);
```

Here, imageView is the name of variable you are using to represent ImageView. Eg.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView1);
```

If you are using ImageButton, change imageView variable to imageButton variable

```
ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
```

**Note** that I am passing variable name.

Comment: just a question, what should I type in the (imageView)

Comment: your imageView variable like this ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);

Comment: i did that and it's giving me an error saying that "into" needs a target

Comment: maybe the problem is in the getApplicationContext part, what should I type in here

Comment: sorry, instead of imageView, you have to write 'staff' -- variable name of your ImageButton

Comment: you can pass 'this' as parameter there instead of getApplicationContext()

Comment: I changed getApplicationContext() to this abut it is saying "staff can't be resolved into a variable"

Comment: Can you ad some part of your code. Just now I tried this protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.ic_launcher).into(imageButton);

Comment: ImageButton staff = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.staffbtn); this line should be before Picasso.with()...

Answer (score 0):

@user3896367 i think below code is use full for you. if you upload image from drawable of web url using this code.

1. download universal image loader jar.
2. put jar in lib folder and add jar.
3. create application class.

   public static void initImageLoader(Context context) {

   ```
   ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
           context)
           .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
           .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
           .discCacheFileNameGenerator(
                   new Md5FileNameGenerator())
           .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
           .build();
   ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
   ```

   }

4.user imageloader like below syntext.

```
  imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageOnLoading(
                    R.drawable.wallpaper_placeholder)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(
                    R.drawable.wallpaper_placeholder)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.wallpaper_placeholder)
            .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(500))
            .cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisk(true)
            .considerExifParams(true)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();.





imageLoader.displayImage(
            URL or ResourceID,
            imageButton, options);
```

try this.